# Facebook edit cookies from script

Tags: javascript, facebook, cookies

I am making a script on Facebook, and the script can't run because of cookies like `c_user`. So I wanted to edit that cookie, but when I did, Facebook logged me out.

Is there any way to do that, or block FB Ajax from reading cookies or only reading specific cookies?